# InfoPath Forms Buttons disappear in Read Mode

Tags: list, infopath

When I click on the Linked Item it opens up an InfoPath form in read mode. 
But no ability to switch to different views (pages) in my form is allowed unless I go to edit mode.

Why do the buttons disappear while in Read mode. 
 Is this a default behavior? Can it be changed? How do I edit the display form to show the buttons?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem but I was using the InfoPath Web Part in a custom page so this solution may not work.

Instead of marking the InfoPath Web Part as read only (in the edit web part UI) I created a new view of the form and [marked the view as read only](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/design-a-read-only-view-HA010211228.aspx). Then you change the web part to use the read only view.

Now you do need to make sure the views that the buttons switch to are also read only otherwise people will be able to edit them.

Answer (score 2):

When using picture buttons, head to the picture button properties and deselect the option that says 'Hide picture button in read-only views'.

Answer (score 2):

Having run in to the same issue, I have found that it is indeed a default setting for InfoPath buttons to only appear when the form is displayed in Edit mode. 
The link below explains that the workaround is to make picture buttons instead, which WILL work in Read mode. To do this, you can click on your current button and click 'Change Control' found under the Properties tab. 
 Alternatively you can create your own buttons and add them to your InfoPath form. If you want to keep the same buttons design and size, you could use a snipping tool to crop them from InfoPath, save locally and then upload back to InfoPath.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33a67c8e-2679-4a77-a413-4e56c8a7295f/infopath-tabbed-views-with-buttons-buttons-dont-show-in-display-mode

Comment: Spot on! :) Nice work!